# Is the probability addition rule commutative?

Tags: probability, statistics

The probability of $A$ and $B$ is the intersection between the venn diagrams for $A$ and $B$.

Then is $P(A \cap B) = P(B \cap A)$?

If so, then surely $\frac{P(A)}{P(B)} = \frac{P(A|B)}{P(B|A)}$.

Is that correct?

Let me rephrase the question.. Why is it always the case that the probability of A happening, then B happening is the same when the order is flipped?

Comment: Yes, correct, unless the assertion involves division by $0$.

Comment: but with certain things, the order matters doesn't it?

Comment: $A\cap B$ and $B\cap A$ are the same set, so the probabilities should be the same.

Comment: Your assertion is correct. But order matters sometimes, for example $\Pr(A\mid B)$ is usually different from $\Pr(B\mid A)$.

Comment: I think your difficulty arises from confusing conditional probability with temporal order. Neither $P(A\cap B)$ nor $P(B|A)$ means the probability that $A$ occurs and thereafter $B$ occurs.  If temporal order is relevant, then the timing information should be part of the definition of the events.  For example, if $A$ refers to something happening today, then for something else ($B$) to happen tomorrow is a different event from it happening yesterday.

Comment: thank you.. I'm new to doing probability so my intuition sometimes gets in the way

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that $A\cap B = B\cap A$ per commutativity of set intersection. Then trivially $P$ should be equal for both as otherwise $P(X) \neq P(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

You are certainly correct that $$\mathbb{P}(\text{A and B}) = \mathbb{P}(\text{B and A})$$

This just because the events "$A$ and $B$" and "$B$ and $A$" are exactly the same event, so by necessity they must have the same probability.

(From now on I will denote $(B \text{ and } A)$ as $(B \land A)$, and analogously for $(A$ and $B) = (A \land B)$.)

The equation you derived from this also appears correct:

$$\frac{\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(B)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B \land A)}{\mathbb{P}(B)\mathbb{P}(B \land A)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A\land B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)} \cdot \frac{\mathbb{P}(A)}{\mathbb{P}(B \land A)} = \frac{\mathbb{P}(A|B)}{\mathbb{P}(B|A)}  $$

Moreover, the above equation *only holds when* $\mathbb{P}(B \land A)>0$. Otherwise $$\frac{\mathbb{P}(B \land A)}{\mathbb{P}(B \land A)}=\frac{0}{0}$$ which is undefined.

In any case, this does not contradict Bayes' Rule.